# how to plot lat lon data to a map using jupyter notebook?

Tags: arcgis-python-api, jupyter-notebook

```
import arcgis
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import SpatialDataFrame

ago_gis = GIS()

search_subset = ago_gis.content.search("Hong Kong Topographic Map")
subset_item = search_subset[5]
subset_map = ago_gis.map(subset_item)
subset_map
```

Then I have a pandas datafram with lat and lon. ANd I want to plot them into the map.

How can I do that?